# Educational Security Vulnerability

Tags: web-browser, exploit

I'm doing a presentation in college. Topic is browser security. I was looking for a browser exploit. I would like to use such thing as a showcase. Do you have any ideas which vulnerability I could present? Of course it could be an exploit which was fixed versions ago. It could for any major browser like Firefox, Chrome, IE ...

Comment: https://www.exploit-db.com/

Comment: May be worth just spinning up webgoat - yes, it is a webserver specifically made to be vulnerable, but it is a great way to show something that LOOKS fine,  but has huge numbers of problems underneath

Comment: Heads up, the question is asking for people's opinions. Different people will have different opinions on which vulnerability to start with. Do some basic research by looking at different educational material (owasp for eg) and decide which one to present.

Comment: @crovers but that's a web app vulnerability, not a browser vulnerability.

Comment: Ugh. You're right. Not a good reading day.

Comment: Thanks, I found an exploit on exploit-db which is easy to understand and DOSes Firefox. Code Excecution/Poping a Shell would be better, but that is fine enough.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing a vulnerability to present will be dependent on what you want to be able to show as proof of the exploit. Do you want to pop a shell? Do you want to escape the sandbox? Run arbitrary code? What browser? What security do you want to test? It will also depend on your skill level and resources. So, it will be difficult for someone else to recommend any particular exploit.

You can look through the exploit-db.com to find PoCs of exploits that match your needs, or you can use the security presenter's best friend: Metasploit.

Use their online search tool: https://www.rapid7.com/db/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=browser&t=m

Metasploit shows you their pre-made exploits, and you can have a number of pre-made effects (shell, run code, etc.). Not every possible exploit has a nice, presentable effect, but you have the ability to narrow your search nicely.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. It isn't really important, what i would access with the exploit: poping a shell or execute code would be best. By now i found an exploit on exploit-db which DOSes Firefox which is easy to understand. I want to showcase security in general (except for privacy which is not my topic). Skill level tends to a lower skill level.